# Marketing Cloud Connector v5 limits?

Tags: marketing-cloud

Here's the setup: SFMC Enterprise 2.0 v5 integration with SFDC Performance Edition.

Does anyone know if there are limits (on either the SFDC or SFMC side) to using the out of the box integration based on the number of records in a report or members in a campaign ? I've heard that there are limits in place but can't find any documentation as to what they are. For example: If a SFDC report contains 73,000 or 250,000 records, will any part of the integration timeout or error due to the volume of records?

Thanks!
Tyler

Comment: If the report fails to refresh (exceeds 10 minute) then the send will fail, but this is more of a SF limitation than a integration limitation. SFMC supports sends to millions of addresses, and does not have any implicit timeout for sends. Any issue will be with refreshing the report.

Comment: @Tyler - Could you please share the setup instructions and installables to Integrate Sales Cloud and Marketing Cloud(ET) applications.